# How to do real readonly properties (accessors => attributs)

Tags: ruby, readonly, accessor

Considering this simple code :

```
class Yeah
  attr_reader :foo
  attr_reader :fool
  attr_reader :feel
  def initialize(foo: "test", fool: {}, feel: [])
    @foo = foo
    @fool = fool
  end
end

test = Yeah::new
pp test
test.fool[:one] = 10
pp test
```

Output :

```
#<Yeah:0x000008019a84a0 @foo="test", @fool={}>
#<Yeah:0x000008019a84a0 @foo="test", @fool={:one=>10}>
```

My Question is, there is a "simple","clean" way, to do read accesors to real readonly Array,Hash attributs or I need to inherit Array or Hash with a lot of locking hard to write, (undef,alias) or using Proxy, delegate or others patterns like this ?

Comment: There are no readonly arrays or hashes in standard ruby.

Comment: Very Good question although (*+1*)

Comment: I want to say, in every case i made accessor for a string reader or writer has a signification, when you try to do obj.accessor= you have the good exception, for hash or arrays in every case i use [] to access, and there is nothing to prevent, but your solution using freeze, seems to be good , thank you !

Comment: @Romain I told you about `Object#freeze`. But once you will make it freeze,you can't unfreeze it.. do remember the same,

Comment: argh ;( yes, or you have to dup, so it's quiet complicated

Comment: or perhaps made the accessor by hand and give the dup or clone (i'm never sure) and freeze it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of something like below :

```
class Yeah
  def self.reader_meth
    %i(foo fool feel).each do |m|
      define_method(m){instance_variable_get("@#{m}").dup.freeze}
    end
  end
  def initialize(foo: "test", fool: {}, feel: [])
    @foo = foo
    @fool = fool
    @feel =feel
  end
  reader_meth
end

test = Yeah.new
test # => #<Yeah:0x8975498 @foo="test", @fool={}, @feel=[]>
test.fool[:one] = 10 # can't modify frozen Hash (RuntimeError)
test # => #<Yeah:0x8975498 @foo="test", @fool={}, @feel=[]>
```

Comment: yes and i could return  @#{m}.dup.freeze if i want an exception to be raised if trying to access, thanks !!

Comment: You can remove the ugly `eval` by using `instance_variable_get`.

Answer (score 1):

Because i want to generalize this solution and to prevent "evil" evals :

i finally, from the Arup solution arrived to this :

```
class Module
  def attr_readonly *syms
    syms.each do |method|
      define_method(method){
        return self.instance_variable_get("@#{method.to_s}").dup.freeze 
      }
    end
  end
end

class Yeah

  attr_reader :foo
  attr_readonly :fool
  attr_reader :feel
  def initialize(foo: "test", fool: {}, feel: [])
    @foo = foo
    @fool = fool
    @feel = feel
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze):

```
class Yeah
  def fool
    @fool.freeze
  end 
  def initialize(fool={})
    @fool = fool
  end
end
```

Comment: but you freeze @fool like Arup explain in comments